# Custom Paging not working in ListView Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, listview, custom-paging

While writing the code below I encountered this error saying `ListViewPageEventsArgs could not be found`.

[image]

I have already added the code below to the template :

```
OnPageIndexChanging="lvListScreen_PageIndexChanging"
```

Do you guys know why I'm having this error?

Comment: I don't know where you got that snippet from, but a ListView does not have `OnPageIndexChanging`, but `OnPagePropertiesChanging`.

Comment: Thanks . I added as per your advice 
    protected void lvListScreen_PagePropertiesChanging(object  sender,     PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
    {
(lvListScreen.FindControl("CustomPager1") as controls_CustomPager).SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
        this.BindListScreenView(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["pg"]));

    }

Comment: Hello now only problem I have is whenever I change my page size from DDL I loose my page start index calculation which is 
     Convert.ToString((miCurrIndex * Convert.ToInt32 (ddlPageSize.SelectedValue))-10 + 1);